# Copying files as password-protected files into an encrypted (password-protected) folder

Tags: password, encryption

I have password protected a folder. I made it password-protected by encrypting it from the right-click 'compress' option. This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4796/how-can-i-simply-password-protect-a-file/4835#4835) helped me do that. All the present files inside my encrypted folder are password-protected now.

I want some more files to be added to the encrypted folder. There is no issues for me in adding new files to that folder. But those files are not password protected as the old files. Is there a way to copy files into that folder as password protected files straight away?

Comment: I had this same problem, someone might have a more elegant solution but mine was just to extract the folder, add the files and then re-encrypt. I know it's not ideal :(