# Is there any way to set up pin or password for a directory and file in ubuntu?

Tags: password, directory

I wanted to lock any directory with a password, is it possible to set up pin or password for any directory or file without using third party tools like cryptkeeper.

Comment: Create an encrypted archive of it

Comment: i want to lock the file not compress it and then encrypt, isn't there any way to just lock any directory?

Comment: Folder locking as you want it does not exist. Even if a program provides such a feature, another program will not care about it. If you really want to lock a folder you have to use encryption. EncFS Encryption with Cryptkeeper as GUI is just fine for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ccrypt` to encrypt files, use it as follows:

```
# prompts for the password, encrypts the file and adds “.cpt”
ccrypt /path/to/file

# prompts for the password, recursively (`-r`) encrypts every file
# in the directory and its subdirectories and adds “.cpt” to every file
ccrypt -r /path/to/dir

# prompts for the password, decrypts (`-d`) the file and removes the “.cpt” ending
ccrypt -d /path/to/file
```

To encrypt a whole directory as one single encrypted file it needs to be packed first, e. g. using `tar`:

```
tar cf - /path/to/dir | ccrypt > /path/to/file.tar.cpt # without compression
tar czf - /path/to/dir | ccrypt > /path/to/file.tgz.cpt # with compression
```

See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ccrypt.1.html) for more!

To simplify this you can write a script with these commands and add it to your file manager to get e. g. “Encrypt” and “Decrypt” options in the dropdown menu.

---

Of course there are other ways to achieve what you want, here some links:

- [How can I easily encrypt a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4796/how-can-i-easily-encrypt-a-file)
- [What is the easiest way to encrypt a dir? (on Ubuntu)](https://superuser.com/questions/182099/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-encrypt-a-dir-on-ubuntu)

Comment: this works but how to use decryption key to access file/directory using GUI?? Do I have to use some third party application?

Comment: You need to decrypt it first to access the packed directory, but you can automate this with e. g. `ccrypt -d /path/to/file && file-roller /path/to/dir`.